# Word for "when somebody does something without realizing it"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

I can't think of this word.  It's when somebody is doing something but they don't realize they are doing it.

For example: Suppose you're a girl and you are falling in love with a guy. When he laughs, you think hes so cute and you love it, but he doesn't realize that you love it. Or maybe the way he kisses your forehead, and he doesn't realize you go crazy over that.

I'm not looking for *oblivious.*

Comment: It seems like you are mentioning two separate things here. (a) doing something without realize you are doing it and (b) liking something someone does without *them* realizing you like it. Can you clarify which question you meant to ask?

Comment: That guy is _naive_ and the girl is in love.

Answer (score 3):

The word you use is 'inadvertent'

He inadvertently turned me into loving him.

Answer (score 2):

Anyways, the description you provide in your sentences doesn't really explain the title of your question.
But let's see if this helps, I provide you with some optional words:

> 1. Hypnotized [Somebody else is controlling your mind]
> 2. Instinctively. [You're doing it with your instinct]
> 3. Subconsciously. [Without your mind working well]
> 4. Mindlessly. [Without thinking]

Those explain when you're doing something without knowing you are.
As for the guy in your explanation, I would say he does it "innocently", he's doing things without knowing how these things make the girl crazily happy.

If you're talking about the girl that likes him like crazy without him knowing, it would be like secret love, or one-sided love.

If I got your question wrong, let me know, to make sure you get what you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

***Clueless, unknowing*** and ***unwitting***, and their associated -ly adverbs can describe people acting/actions done without a knowledge of their affective impression on other people.

Answer (score 0):

I think **innocence** is the key. The guy is actually not aware of the results of his actions.

May be **UNAWARE** is one simple word you have to use.

Answer (score -1):

Impulsive. Check some synonyms to this word. Impulsive comes to my mind from what you describe.

I think impulsive can be used, since somebody is doing something without properly realizing and its after-effects, it can be suggestive of an impulse of doing something.

I think the example given doesn't justify the question properly. For that example this word IMPULSIVE should not be used.

For the question asked in paragraph one, it's fine by me.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. That prompted me to rethink my answer after reading the question profoundly.