# Word to describe a person who knows the names of things without knowing how they work

Tags: single-word-requests

Benjamin Franklin once said,

> “What signifies knowing the names, if you know not the nature of
>   things?”

I'm wondering if there is a single word to describe a person like this.

E.g:

> 1)A word to describe a person who collects cars but doesn't know how cars work.
>
> 2)A word to describe a person who puts computers together with out knowing how computers function.

Comment: *Nobody* really knows how today's computers function.

Comment: Management material.

Comment: You have two different concepts here. There are people who collect butterflies without any idea how they work. For those, *barbarians* is too good a word. But I would guess that all our devices are put together by people with no idea how they work, so for them the right phrase is "trained assembly-line workers". I don't see how you could squeeze both those ideas into one word without getting a headache.

Comment: Similar question : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133560/word-for-when-somebody-does-something-without-realizing-it

Comment: I know many many people who go out and buy the latest mobile/cell phone by a famous fruit named company and they know nothing about how it works. Why should a car collector know how a car works?

Comment: I would suggest the phenomenon is so widespread it doesn't have a particular name. It's the way things are; the *status quo.* Many people will recognise a gyroscope but not have the faintest idea how it stays upright.

Comment: Everybody uses a smartphone/car these days. Only a few know how these machines work.

Comment: [Nomenclator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclator_(nomenclature)) may be possible.

Comment: A *non-technical* person - [definition 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/non-technical). It doesn't address knowing the nomenclature, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call it *feeling maayo*. It means someone who feels he/she is good at something but he/she really isn't.

Or *feeling brayt*, from English *feeling* + *bright*, someone who thinks he/she is smart.

In the same structure:

- *feeling gwapa* - thinks she's pretty but really not.
- *feeling dato* - social climber

Comment: Which variant of English is this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Someone who tries to deceive others by making them believe they know more than they do: bluffer.
2. Someone who genuinely learns names of things without really understanding how they work. In your example, someone who learns to put together a computer and the names of their parts but doesn't quite understand yet how these parts are able to work together: novice or hobbyist.
3. As someone commented on your question, nowadays, we all know names of things without knowing how they work. For instance, smartphones, cars, even simple things like electricity, everybody can change a bulb but does everyone really understand how electricity works? In this group I would say that the term is simply: user.